# How to connect ec2 Instance on aws to my company VPN

Tags: amazon-ec2, vpn

I have couple of ec2 Instances on amazon. I want to connect these ec2 instances to my company VPN. I want to do this, so that I can connect to Oracle which is on-premise from an application which is running on  ec2

Answer (score 0):

you can ssh to the ec2 instance from your company vpn

Answer (score 0):

If you have correctly configured your VPN between your office and your AWS VPC (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_VPN.html), then you should check your VPC NACLs, Security Groups and Route Tables to be able to ssh between the different servers and the EC2 Instances.